# Change Conversation Id for an Outlook 2010 Message

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can you change the Conversation Id of a message to put them on a older conversation? Have you to use some VB script code?
I tried to change the subject but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try the macro in this article: [Merge or Split Conversations.](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/merge-split-conversations/) Select the message that should be added to a conversation, hold shift and select a message in the conversation it belongs in, then run the macro.